# Bootstrap text input not rendering properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

One of my text field inputs is not rendering properly. I'm using bootstrap. Here's what it looks like.

[image]

This is the code I'm using.

```
<div class="modal-body">

  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="input1">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="input2">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text2" class="form-control" id="input2" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

I noticed that when then input `type` is exactly `text` the input field is not rendered properly, but when the `type` is anything else, the input field is ok. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: which version of bootstrap you are using and it works in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/11846/

Comment: `id="input13"` instead of `id="input1"`. Is that just a typo ?

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada Yes that's just a typo.

Comment: @SrinivasPai I'm using version 3.3.5. That's odd that it renders properly in jsfiddle. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: is `type=text2` in the second input also a typo?

Comment: can you reproduce your issue in fiddle? we can check it.

Comment: @wero `text2` is not a typo. I'm demonstrating that when I specify `text2` it works and `text` does not.

Comment: @David The Code and the Output image doesn't actually match. Can you please reproduce your issue with same code in fiddle ?

Comment: david: why don't you inspect the input element in firebug and see what styles are applied instead of letting us guess about typos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like, and this is just a guess without being able to see all of your code, you have some style that is matching `input[type="text"]`, and that is what's giving you the odd result.

This is not something wrong with bootstrap, rather, it's probably something on your end.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine, this means you may have old Bootstrap, or some style is overriding default `input[text]` and notice, bootstrap doesn't care about `type="text2"` as  by default is type of text

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="modal-body">

  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="input1">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="input2">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text2" class="form-control" id="input2" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
  </form>

</div>
```